# Kurento Media Server events to indicate video faults

Tags: kurento

I am using KMS for video security application, that has to work 24/7. Currently the behavior is unstable and video is freezing periodically.

I am looking for a way to indicate this problematic behavior. I can't find find any example of using KMS events for this type of issues.

Could someone please point me out to a code snippet or to any info describing a way to indicate video faults like (bad quality, freezing etc.)

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no particular events for that, except in case media stops flowing. However, you can use the `getStats` method from one particular endpoint, and check for different WebRTC statistics that will inform you about the quality of the media.

In any case, that behaviour is quite odd, and you should check under which circumstances it is produced, just in case you are reaching the limits of your box or your network. Also, please use the latest version of the media server (6.5.1 as of now)